# Questions about java's while loop and checkers

Tags: java

I am writing a Java program that let user input a number, then the program combine 5,8,and 9 to get user's input number.

I want to achieve following samples:

1.

> what is your number that you what to find the combination?
>
> 8
>
> your number has 1 eights

2.

> what is your number that you what to find the combination?
>
> 13
>
> your number has 1 fives and 1 eights

3.

> what is your number that you what to find the combination?
>
> 11
>
> invalid number

Here are codes that I wrote:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class combine {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println("what is your number that you what to find the combination? ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (num < 5){
            System.out.println("invalid number");
            System.exit(0);
        }
//Begin Looping
        for (int g=0; g<=1000000;g++){
//Find the the number left after minus g*5
            int left = num - g*5;
//Check the combination of 5 and 8
            if (left%8 == 0){
                System.out.format("your number has %d fives and %d eights\n",g,left/8);
                System.exit(0);
            }
//Check the combination of 5 and 9
            if (left%9 == 0){
                System.out.format("your number has %d fives and %d nines\n",g,left/9);
                System.exit(0);
            }
//Check the combination of 8 and 9
            while (false){     //This while loop doesn't work. It fails compile.
                int left2 = nuggets_num - g*8;
                try{
                    if (left%8 == 0){
                            System.out.format("your number has %d eights and %d nines\n",g,left/8);
                            System.exit(0);
                    }
                    if (left%8 != 0){
                        System.out.println("invalid number");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("invalid number");
    }
}
//I am a beginner and I know that reading my codes might be painful, sorry about that:(
```

As I mentioned, my `while` loop doesn't work. So my program could't find the combination of "17", which should be 1 eight and 1 nine. How to fix it?

Also, my program's outputs are not clean enough. For example, if user input "8", my program would output"your number has 0 fives and 1 eights". How to add checkers to avoid these conditions? Like output "your number has 1 eights" instead of the former output.

Comment: What do you except to happen? you wrote that it should loop based on false, which basicly means never, and throws a compiler error if you directly write a never changing false in it

Comment: It is able to compile without the while loop. I am not quite understand the while loop. I tried to google the methods of it but I couldn't edit it properly into my program.

Comment: Maybe you should modify your logic. With your problem, how would you represent 14?

Comment: I tested that(after delete the while loop I wrote). It gives the output of "your number has 1 fives and 1 nines".

Comment: Yes. Is it correct? Shouldn't it be 1 Nines and 1 Fives? I hope you understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `while(false)` which means that this loop will never be executed. Java compiler is intelligent enough to stop you to compile something that it **knows** will not run.

As for your logic, when you deduct maximum multiple of 5's from some number (which means that you are doing modulus by 5), the remainder will never be more than 4! So, you should do something like below:

1. Divide the input by 9. This will give you the count of 9's in that input.
2. Modulus the input by 9. This will give you the remainder, which will be less than or equal to 8.
3. Perform step 1 and 2 with 8 and 5, respectively.

Use the output of above algorithm to format your output string.

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic misunderstanding of the division and modulus operators.
You're trying to divide a number by a specific digit to "get rid" of it, but that only works when you're diving by multiplications of 10 (assuming you're working in the decimal system).

For example, `(1985 / 10) = 198`, but `888 / 8` does not equal `88`!

The same goes for the % operator - `(350 % 3)` will not return `50`! It's actually equal to `2`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't think this is an error. Suppose user input 28, the program will first check "fives"(it found 2 fives when I tested my program). Then the program calculate 28-2*5(which correspond with the code int left = num - g*5;). We got 18 at this time. Afterward, the program used left%8==0 and left%9==0 to statements to test 18. Then it find out 18 is belongs to left%9==0. So the output was "your number has 2 fives and 2 nines".